# SNMP Network traffic difference between ifInOctet and ifHCInOctet

Tags: networking, cisco, monitoring, switch, snmp

I try to monitor some Cisco 2960x Switch devices and I know there are the SNMP OID's ifInOctets (32-bit Counter) and ifHCinOctets (64-bit Counter). Can someone explain me whats the difference between those Counters and which one I should use for a GigabitEthernet Interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Difference is the maximal value can be set between 2^32 and 2^64.

With 32 bits, you can up to 4 294 967 295 octets (approximately 4.2 Go).
With 64 bits, you can up to 18 446 744 073 709 552 000 octets (approximately 18,4 To).

Example for speed (show 4.2 Go instead real value - like
TenGigabitEthernet or more) or total traffic (restart from 0 when 4.2 Go as reachable).

Today, 32 bits is very limited and can be reachable very fast.

For compatibility purpose, int32 still exist, but I recommend you to use int64.

Comment: But when I add ifInOctet and ifHCInOctet to a graph it shows different values. That's something I don't understand

Comment: Can you provide an example of returned value ?
Remember, ifInOctet is limited to 4.2 Go.